# How to get a background image that's not blurred inside a container but blurred outside

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the image inside my login form not blurred but keep the background outside of the login form blurred
[What I'm trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JjCp.jpg)

[What I currently have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMPYO.png)

Tried backdrop filter and etc

```css
.bg-image {
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: scale(1.1);
    background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/DWvpCWD/login-bg.jpg");
    filter: blur(3px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.bg-text {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
    padding: 40px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-image"></div>
<div class="bg-text">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="login-register">
            <a href="/login" class="active">Login</a>
            <a href="/register">Register</a>
        </div>

        <div>
            <form action="post" class="form">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password">
                </div>

                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input class="checkbox-effect checkbox-effect-1" id="get-up-1" type="checkbox" name="remember">
                    <label for="get-up-1">Remember Me</label>
                </div>

                <button type="submit">Login</button>

                <a class="forgot-password" href="">Forgot Password?</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Trying to get the image that's behind the .bg-text container to not be blurred

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible issue. Provide the relevant `HTML` as well. Also, do add a public URL for images (not a local URL)

Comment: If there was no direct solution, you can add a secondary div around your text area and set the background again without blur effect inside that. You may need to play with background size and position to achieve the deisred result.

Comment: Afaik, there is no direct method except repeating the Bg in the inner div as well. I found something similar being done here but it is a bit complex: https://codepen.io/paulobrien/pen/abLbBqo

Comment: try [mask-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image) or [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have two background elements layered on top of one another. The one at the back is not blurred. The one in front is blurred, but has the central area masked with a pair of linear gradients, so the unblurred background behind shows through.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.d1, .d2 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://picsum.photos/id/28/1920/1080);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.d1 {
  z-index: -2;
}

.d2 {
  z-index: -1;
  mask-image: linear-gradient(black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%), linear-gradient(90deg, black 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 75%, black 75%);
  filter: blur(4px);
}

.login {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  border: 2px solid rgb(255 255 255 / 0.7);
  background: rgb(0 0 0 / 0.5);
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="d1"></div>
<div class="d2"></div>
<div class="login">Username<br>Password<br>etc</div>
```

After running this snippet, use the **full page** link for best results.

Comment: The alignment isn't quite right, because of the border, you'd want calc(25% + border-width) in the mask-image, but overall, I believe this solution could be made more modular.

Comment: Alignment fixed

Answer (score 3):

`backdrop-filter` combined with `mask` can do it and you don't have to duplicate the image:

```css
.bg-image {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  transform: scale(1.1);
  background-image: url("https://i.ibb.co/DWvpCWD/login-bg.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.bg-text {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: white;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 300px;
  container-type: inline-size; /* use this to avoid the extra scroll*/
}

.bg-text:before {
  content:"";
  position: fixed;
  /* a very big inset and padding to overflow outside */
  inset: -100vmax;
  padding: 100vmax;
  /**/
  /* the mask will keep only the padding area (the overflowing part) */
  -webkit-mask: 
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0) content-box,
    linear-gradient(#000 0 0);
  -webkit-mask-composite: xor;
          mask-composite: exclude;
   backdrop-filter: blur(10px); /* apply the blur */
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-image"></div>
<div class="bg-text">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="login-register">
      <a href="/login" class="active">Login</a>
      <a href="/register">Register</a>
    </div>

    <div>
      <form action="post" class="form">
        <div class="input-group">
          <label for="username">Username</label>
          <input type="text" name="username">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input type="password" name="password">
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
          <input class="checkbox-effect checkbox-effect-1" id="get-up-1" type="checkbox" name="remember">
          <label for="get-up-1">Remember Me</label>
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Login</button>

        <a class="forgot-password" href="">Forgot Password?</a>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In Safari 17.4, the image is not blurred. Works in Chrome. Perhaps `-webkit-backdrop-filter` is required?

Comment: The main advantage is that the size of the mask is set automagically to the content-box.  However it's kinda sad to see there is still a need for that 100vmax padding, I suppose that makes the compositor deal with a huge square and possibly waste a lot of resource on wider screens Or maybe they're able to do the clipping before the filtering somehow, but I doubt that, moreover on backdrop-filter.

Comment: Oh it seems `container-type: inline-size;` doesn't work as expected in Firefox... It overflows there.